# Nifi ConsumeKafka processor, Null message based routing

Tags: apache-nifi, tombstone

Am using ConsumeKafka processor in nifi. I have a scenario to check if kafka message received is a null message. kafka tombstone scenario basically. And do the routing on that basis. how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-6-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafka_2_6/index.html

The `ConsumeKafka_2_6` processor Writes Attributes:

`kafka.tombstone`   Set to `true` if the consumed message is a tombstone message

---

So, you just need to use `RouteOnAttribute` after ConsumeKafka_2_6 with check if kafka.tombstone=true